# For iTerm2, how do I make the working directory appear in the window title?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I recently switched to iTerm2 from the default Terminal app and have a usability issue.

On Terminal, the working directory you are in shows up on the title bar along with the process and pixel size.  For example, when you click on Window to switch between different Terminal sessions, you'd see: working_directory - process - pixel_size.

On iTerm2, unfortunately only the process shows in the title bar.  So if I'm working in multiple iTerm2 windows on different directories, I can't easily differentiate which is which when I click on Window to choose one.  I know I can easily switch between iTerm2 windows once I select one, but I'd like to identify exactly which window I want right away.  (By the way, I use Witch, and Command-tabbing doesn't help either because here again only the process shows up on the list).

Any suggestions?  I looked through all the preferences and didn't see anything.  Creating profiles isn't exactly what I'm after--I'd just like to see the current working directory in iTerm2 window titles.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With the `\033]0;TEXT\007` escape sequence.

Example of use in Bash: `echo -ne "\033]0;$PWD\007"`

Which you could add to your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` if you use Bash, or otherwise attach to you `PS1` so it gets re-evaluated often.

Example: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$PWD\007"'`

Comment: This works. Just to be pedantic, add the export line listed above to your ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: This is awesome.  Thanks so much; this helped me understand that the answer is really about bash programming and has nothing to do with iTerm vs Terminal.  As a follow up for anyone else, please see http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#s3 and http://www.linfo.org/echo.html.  Thanks again!

Comment: and to get just the last segment of the path `echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"` (with thanks to https://github.com/barryclark/bashstrap for showing the way)

Comment: @Spencer: There is no reason to export the PROMPT_COMMAND shell variable, and in general one should not export a shell variable unless you have a specific need to share the variable with _every program run by the shell_. By default, variables that are used by the shell should not be exported; only export variables that are meant to be transmitted to other processes. `~/.bashrc` will be run by every interactive shell, so they don't need to inherit the variables set by this script.

Comment: Well, exporting is how you use PROMPT_COMMAND... And it is generally better for complicated things [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058325/what-is-the-difference-between-ps1-and-prompt-command)

Comment: In PowerShell: `Write-Host "\`e]0;$PWD\`a" -NoNewLine`

Comment: It works but once you ssh into a remote shell the working directory doesn't get updated. Still looking for a solution for that.

Comment: Is there a way that I can have this be the default behavior every time I open a new iTerm window? I don't want to have to use the above command every time.

Comment: @ChrisNielsen you would edit your .profile, or your shell's conf file...

Comment: @kapoko Because your prompt setting on the remote shell doesn't set the window title.  Fix that.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using zsh (which is the default in macOS 10.15+), put this in your ~/.zshrc instead:

```
if [ $ITERM_SESSION_ID ]; then
precmd() {
  echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"
}
fi
```

You can also spell `\033` as `\e` and `\007` as `\a`.

Answer (score 16):

Possibly a simpler answer is to use the [string interpolation](https://iterm2.com/documentation-scripting-fundamentals.html) functionality offered by iTerm 2. Providing:

```
\(currentTab.currentSession.path)
```

in settings would result in a changed Window title. The option is accessible through <kbd>Preferences</kbd><kbd>>></kbd><kbd>Profiles</kbd><kbd>>></kbd><kbd>[Profile we need to modify]</kbd><kbd>>></kbd><kbd>Window</kbd>

[image: settings]
*Settings*

[image: RESULTS]
*Window title*

Comment: Wow... finally the right answer that I was just looking for!!! If you want this to work for TABS, use `\(current.Session.path)`

Comment: Fixing @vanHoesel's answer: for tabs it's `\(currentSession.path)`

Comment: More variables are documented here if interested: https://iterm2.com/documentation-variables.html

Comment: That's definetely the right way of doing that, thanks!

Comment: Any way to show relative path like `~`, `~/Desktop` instead of absolute path?

Answer (score 2):

I like this answer from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/phette23/5270658) to add it to the *tab* title

```
# put this in your .bash_profile
if [ $ITERM_SESSION_ID ]; then
  export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033];${PWD##*/}\007"; ':"$PROMPT_COMMAND";
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can relatively easily set the tab title in iTerm2 on macOS to the current working directory by placing the following in your `~/.zshrc` profile:

```
# Set iTerm Tab Title to Current Working Directory
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

iterm_tab_title() {
  echo -ne "\e]0;${PWD##*/}\a"
}
add-zsh-hook precmd iterm_tab_title
```

It uses a [precmd hook function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) to execute before each prompt, setting the tab title by echoing out the current working directory.

For good measure, some [Oh My Zsh themes](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes) mess around with the Terminal window title, so setting `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` fixes this.<sup>[†](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough karma to comment, but if you want it to show `~/dir` instead of `/users/username/dir` you can use

```
if [ $ITERM_SESSION_ID ]; then
precmd() {
  echo -ne "\033]0;$(dirs)\007"
}
fi
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Under Preferences -> Profiles -> General -> Basics...

Set the Title to PWD only.

[image]